# SQL select sum of column with value in multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have a table in SQL Server, the columns return PID and Val1 I am trying to add 2 sum columns of certain each PID.

The `ValTotal` column should be a Sum of every Val with that `PID`.

So for example, in the select bellow, you can see that the `Val1Total` and `Val2Total` are a `SUM` of the `Val1` and `Val2` for the `PID` of 1.

```
PID  Val1  Val1Total 
---------------------
1    10    20  'See how both (1) columns have the same total      
2    10    10       
1    10    20  'See how both (1) columns have the same total
4    10    10      
3    10    10
```

I have searched the web and cannot find what I am looking for, Is this even something I can do?

Any help or advice would be appreciate, thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide your query.  Sample data would also help.

Comment: not sure what are you asking here. is the ValTotal sum of val1Total and val2Total in your example, or the val1Total and val2Total are the columns which you would like to add.

Comment: apologies my question is not clear, we can assume that it is just a simple table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are just looking for window functions:

```
select pid, val1, val2,
       sum(val1) over (partition by pid) as val1total,
       sum(val2) over (partition by pid) as val2total
from t;
```

Comment: this was what I was after, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using OLAP functions (Window functions) in SQL. But I am not sure if MySQL supports them. Check if Mysql supports `SUM() OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...)`

If not you can achieve that using joins on the same table. Sample code is given below:

```
select  A.PID,
    A.Val1,
    A.Val2,
    B.Val1Total,
    B.Val2Total,
From    Table A
Inner Join (Select PID, sum(Val1) as Val1Total, sum(Val2) as Val2Total
        From Table) B
on A.PID = B.PID
```